# Solr multivalued field searchs only the first 2000 values why?

Tags: solr, limit

I have a single document with a multivalued field that stores text(say tag). Each entry size is an average 20 characters . This multivalued field can have a huge number of entries. In my case around 3000. Where i query on this field it searches only the first 2000 entries. If i query for anything more than the 2000th entry no results are found why is is? Even though these values are stored and returned when a search within 2000 is done.

I got to the number 2000 by looking at the search results are querying until i got no results.

I am doing a very simple query on that field. Any ideas?

Comment: Got the answer: Needed to increase the maxFieldLength in solr config.

Comment: you can make that comment an answer and accept your own answer.